# TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeHead' of undefined node js

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm running a real vanilla server in node and this error keeps popping up, i can't even track it because in my view there isn't anything that could be wrong?

```
function send404(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.write('Error 404: resource not found. ');
        response.end();
    };
```

Server.js

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        var filePath = false;

        if (request.url === '/') {
            filePath = 'public/index.html';
        } else {
            filePath = 'public' + request.url;
        }
        var absPath = './' + filePath;
        serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
        var filePath = false;

        if (request.url === '/' ) {
            filePath = 'public/index.html';
        } else {
            filePath = 'public' + request.url;
        }

        var absPath = './' + filePath;
        serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
    });


    server.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('Server listening on port 3000.');
    });
```

Comment: did you try logging the response variable to see if it's even being called.  My guess is that it's returning undefined.

Comment: your right its not, how do i call this?

Comment: try calling send404(request, response) within your createServer callback.  My guess is send404 is not being passed the arguments you are expecting.

Comment: thanks man your right, i was missing arguments in send404.